# Do we need GDPR policy statement if we do not use Cookies or obtain personal information from users?

Tags: gdpr, privacy, european-union, germany, cookies

I am developing a static website to provide some blogs and documentation related to company products. It's a simple website and we have decided not to use any `Cookies` or obtain personal information from users.

The website will be hosted in Germany, Europe. I would like to know if it is required for me to show the privacy policy with GDPR compliance even though we do not obtain personal information from users.

If required to show a privacy policy, then can you please guide me to such a template which I can use? Because I saw a few templates, but all those templates indicate that they obtain the user information, so I am unable to figure out what needs to be added in my GDPR privacy policy.

Comment: I marked this question as a duplicate of one where I wrote an answer that addresses most of your points (yes you are processing personal data, and consequently do need a privacy notice, in addition to the Impressumspflicht you have anyway). I don't think there are good templates, but Art 13 GDPR lists all the points that you must mention.